# ormlite createTableIfNotExists fails if table has index

Tags: mysql, indexing, ormlite

I have a simple class like this :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "VlpTag")
public class VlpTag implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4912974444196844860L;

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "buid", canBeNull = false, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private VlpVirtualApp vApp;

    @DatabaseField
    private long lastUpdated;

    @DatabaseField(index=true)
    private String tagValue;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_INTEGER)
    private TagType tagType;

    public static enum TagType {
        UUID, TAG
    };

    public VlpTag() {
        // needed by ormlite
    }
}
```

Then I use TableUtils to create the table if it doesn't exists :

```
TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(MySQLConnection.getInstance()
            .getConnection(), VlpTag.class);
```

If the table doesn't exist, there is not problem, although it the table exists, ORMLite raise an exception saying that the index exists :

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL statement failed: CREATE INDEX `VlpTag_tagValue_idx` ON `VlpTag` ( `tagValue` )
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doStatements(TableUtils.java:464)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:440)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:220)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(TableUtils.java:61)
    at com.banctecmtl.ca.vlp.controller.listvmupdater.DatabaseUpdater.<init>(DatabaseUpdater.java:47)
    at com.banctecmtl.ca.vlp.controller.listvmupdater.ListVMUpdater.<init>(ListVMUpdater.java:42)
    at com.banctecmtl.ca.vlp.controller.VlpController.<init>(VlpController.java:75)
    at com.banctecmtl.ca.vlp.view.webview.server.VlpControllerServiceImpl.init(VlpControllerServiceImpl.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:616)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate key name 'VlpTag_tagValue_idx'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1362)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcCompiledStatement.runExecute(JdbcCompiledStatement.java:62)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doStatements(TableUtils.java:458)
    ... 29 more
```

This bug has already been [reported on the bug list](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3437795&group_id=297653&atid=1255989) and I was wondering it was resolved 
beacause I have the same problem. I use MYSQL and `ormlite-core-4.33.jar`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here, or there is a problem with that?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that David.  I've seen that bug in the list for a while but it's not been a priority to fix it.  I'll bump it up a bit.  Ping me via my website if you don't hear anything in a couple of days: http://256.com/gray/

Comment: All right, actually it's not a big problem yet as our database will probably stay quite small, but others run into the same issue it could be nice for them if they knew what was going on :)

Comment: Yeah.  I'll add a comment to the bug.  You can always feel free to comment on a bug as well.  Posting unit tests that demonstrate it always helps too ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I've add added a fix for this issue. See https://github.com/ethangui/ormlite-core-4.42-sources

When constructing the CREATE TABLE statement

original solution:

after adding the PRIMARY KEY statement:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST table_name ...columns... PRIMARY KEY (id)`

it concats:

`,CREATE INDEX index_name ON column name;`

which essentially makes it two separate SQL queries. First it creates the table, then it adds the index. It works as expected - creates the table and adds the index - unless a table already exists with the appropriate. In such case, the first statement would do nothing, while the second statement still tries to create an index, which would subsequently fail.

my solution:
instead of adding another query after CREATE TABLE, I moved ADD INDEX inside of the first statement. Therefore,

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST table_name ...columns... PRIMARY KEY (id)`

then

`,KEY index_name (column_name);`

Therefore, if table exists, the entire statement would be skipped, thus, no table nor index will be created.

THINGS TO NOTE:

1. Currently implementation only checks for index=true data field annotation for adding indexes.
2. If table pre-exists without index, the entire statement would still be skipped, thus no index would be added.
3. Only tested with MySQL.